# Hopf bifurcation for competitive system

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am attempting to visually investigate a Hopf bifurcation in the xz plane in a competitive system but have no idea how to input some of these values so I may adjust some of the parameters as necessary. I am just new to plotting these, sorry. The biggest confusion I have lies in mixing the functions of x(with their own parameters - see example of f(x)) with a derivative w.r.t. time. This is, of course, the nondimensionalized system.

I have 2 systems:

x'[t] = f(x)(F(x)-z)

z'[t] = z(G(x)-z)

and for example:

f(x)=(x/k)(1+a+bx)

I have the parameters k, b, and a to input for this one...

I saw some suggestion in some mathematica examples that showed renaming x'[t]=f(x,z)=... that looked promising but it is still a bit unclear.

I am trying to make NDSolve work for this but perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: can you try to write the equations more neatly so people can have a better look?

Comment: Is that better? I am a bit tired today so yes it did look horrible. Sorry about that

Comment: yes, it seems much better. thanks

Comment: For a start, this would require proper Mathematica syntax. So something like: `f[x_] := x/k*(1 + a + b*x)` and `x'[t] = f[x] (F[x[t]] - z[t])`.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with the syntax. I just wrote it as it is for brevity. You did help with one thing I missed though :)